# Radio Button Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular 2.

I have these radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Bonds">
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Income">
```

I want to call a function on myComponent Class with something like this

```
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Bonds" (change)=doSomething()>
```

where

```
doSomething(){
 console.log(`Hello`);
}
```

The functions is not called. I have tried with (click) too.
But it doesn't work

Comment: check error in console. Do you see any?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the double quotes.

(change)=doSomething() should be (change)="doSomething()"

Have a look at the following plunkr in src/test-item-radio.ts:

```
@Component({
selector: 'test-item-radio',
template: `
  <div>
    Answer: {{ answer }}
  </div>
  <div class="radio" *ng-for="#option of itemData">
        <label>{{option.id}}
            <input type="radio" [value]="option.id"
                   (change)="doSomething()" name="radio-list" [checked]='answer==option.id'>
            <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
`,
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor],
providers: []
})
export class TestItemRadio {

@Input()
itemData;

answer: string;

constructor() {
  console.log(this.itemData);
  this.answer=2;
}

doSomething() {
  alert('hello');
}
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/F4ukpS2lExNJvb1CYwbF?p=info

Comment: `directives` on `@Component` are deprecated now in latest Angular version

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Seems to be alpha verison, so there are other "issues" as well: `*ng-for="#option of itemData"`

Answer (score 1):

change the event from (change) to (click) and include the function in double quotes "dosomething()" like below code

pass a value of radio button to differentiate from one radiobutton with another  in the function like "dosomething('Bonds')"

like below code

```
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Bonds" (click)="doSomething('Bonds')">
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Income" (click)="doSomething('Income')">
```

write the function in the component class

```
doSomething(value:string):void {
  alert(value);
}
```

I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can get radio value by passing `$event.target.value` as argument for `doSomething` function as below :

```
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Bonds" (change)="doSomething($event.target.value)">Bonds
<input type="radio" name="jobb" value="Income" (change)="doSomething($event.target.value)">Income
```

function in Component :

```
doSomething(data: any){
  console.log('Hello ' + data);
}
```

You can check Plunker at : https://plnkr.co/edit/MqUD0fGCUcF7brMEx1rq

Comment: OP says *The functions is not called* :)